# How to compare an image stored in the device with the scanned frame value using camera?

Tags: android

I'm having an image stored in the android device. I need to compare the image with the video stream captured using its camera. If a match found we need to display a message.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be no so trivial question. Definitely need to research for available image processing libs online, otherwise extract DIB section (binary data of the image, as RGB or ARGB) and then compare with streaming image with possible round percentage.

It's just idea, and not so real answer.